# Get name of the named range corresponding to the given range

Tags: c#, excel, named-ranges

How can I get name of the [Excel named range](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/exceltips/qt/named_range.htm) from cell range?

For example, I'm naming "A1" cell as "Test" in Excel editor, then I want to get this name in C# from "A1" Excel range.

Following is what I tried but it`s not giving me the result I require.

```
Xcelrng = (Excel.Range)Excel.Application.Cells[XcelRow, XcelCol];
```

From any other excel elements like value, formula, address I use, I am also unable to get the name of the named range.

Comment: You need to edit the question to make sense (and respect the rules). Do you want to find a cell's name when you have the address, eg get "Test" when you have "A1" ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:yeah I need to get the name I gave based on address. Sorry for trouble.

Comment: Did you check the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.name(v=office.15).aspx) property of the range?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:Yeah. It doesnt have the name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the named range of a cell - VSTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764491/how-to-find-the-named-range-of-a-cell-vsto)

Comment: I still didnt get the answer I need. Can somebody please use the code of mine and get the name?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a range of cells you may try like this:

```
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range x = (Excel.Range) worksheet.get_Range(worksheet.Cells[1, 1], worksheet.Cells[10,10]);
```

And if you are looking to get the names then try like this:

```
Workbook.Sheet.Names("Test").RefersToRange.Value;
```

Comment: In "x" in your case I dont find the name I gave.